# How to properly type return type of a reduce function

Tags: typescript

I cannot figure out how to type a return type of a reduce function. Please have a look at the ts playground link. I'm providing a callback function to the reduce fn that takes two params as number[] and returns a number,  but typescript throws an error saying that return type of this operation supposed to be number[]. As a workaround I've tried to explicitly provide a return "as number" but ts throws again saying that it might be a mistake. So the question is how can I force it and change reduce signature to return the type I want?

```
export function sumOfIntervals(intervals: [number, number][]): number {
  const mergedIntervals: [number, number][] = [];
  intervals
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => {
      const [prevMin, prevMax] = prev;
      const [currMin] = curr;

      if (prevMax > currMin && currMin > prevMin) {
          mergedIntervals.push([Math.min(...prev, ...curr), Math.max(...prev, ...curr)])
      } else {
          mergedIntervals.push(curr)
      }
      return curr;
    })
  return mergedIntervals.reduce(([a, b], [c, d]) => ((b - a) + (d - c))); /* err */
}
```

Error:

> Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)

[Code snippet here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&keyofStringsOnly=false&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&noImplicitOverride=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.4.3&fbclid=IwAR3G84AaHQOVzFgW6FVDIftEoQNQAH0eU3FDQIXB6x2BPWq6zVAAQQkA2_c#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM5IC2A8ggJIozBQBuAhgDZ4AUml19TAXHANopEARtQA0cAYWFQAur2kBKHhKlwA3gCg4cNDjzxC1AObAAJhSq1GeHvyGjxdmXLgBePtIDcmuGwuc83loAdHjQMMzMvHTSYryCCq4AfHB0cAC0cILygXBBUKZIaMARYPk0YmhIUFDySWo5WjooenylwDQAsmxibZ10INKucL1eWmPauvC8ldVdKINuM1BeDT4IcMy9Hf1wyUtzcABkh9pVUAfJW2y1GuN3cAZQxmbslkxBYEh4ABaR2zDfIKENjMIJg3piMFBJbyMT-QGEfqg8FlSFgmEKVYAXzgwCYwHq93Gj2e5g4Vg%20X1%20MOxq3yMCquCWozGWOyWnpjIeRlMZLeeDyBSKESiYnisTQYhMCRcyQignSKVqAGoNiZFWh5FqvFj1EA)

Comment: Your first argument of the callback function is the previous value. After one iteration, you return a number from the callback, it can not be destructured.

Comment: Please include the plain text of your [mre] in the question; an external IDE link is great but is not a substitute for the plaintext version (the question should be self-contained without requiring that someone go to a site external to Stack Overflow to read it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending from Eduard's comment, in your use case of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you are returning a number, but you are attempting to destructure a `number` into `[number, number]` in the first argument. If you simply want to sum all the differences, you don't need to unpack it:

```
return mergedIntervals.reduce((acc, [a, b]) => acc + (b-a), 0);
```

That is because the current value (second positional argument) will always be your `[number, number]` tuple, and you simply want to add their difference into an accumulator, which has a type of `number`.

[See fixed example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&keyofStringsOnly=false&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&noImplicitOverride=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.4.3&fbclid=IwAR3G84AaHQOVzFgW6FVDIftEoQNQAH0eU3FDQIXB6x2BPWq6zVAAQQkA2_c#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwM5IC2A8ggJIozBQBuAhgDZ4AUml19TAXHANopEARtQA0cAYWFQAur2kBKHhKlwA3gCg4cNDjzxC1AObAAJhSq1GeHvyGjxdmXLgBePtIDcmuGwuc83loAdHjQMMzMvHTSYryCCq4AfHB0cAC0cILygXBBUKZIaMARYPk0YmhIUFDySWo5WjooenylwDQAsmxibZ10INKucL1eWmPauvC8ldVdKINuM1BeDT4IcMy9Hf1wyUtzcABkh9pVUAfJW2y1GuN3cAZQxmbslkxBYEh4ABaR2zDfIKENjMIJg3piMFBJbyMT-QGEfqg8FlSFgmEKVYAXzgwCYwHq93Gj2e5g4Vg%20X1%20MOxq3yMCquCWozGWPkKy09MZDyMpjJbzweQKRQidDQaFidDE8VqLmSYrQcAA1BtBGk6LC4AAGdnqLHqIA).

Comment: +1. OP: The typing works like this because Terry is using the two-arg overload of `Array.reduce` with `number` as `U`, [which TypeScript declares here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cec2fda9a53620dc545a2c4d7b0156446ab145b4/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1183-L1195).